# I got an unexpected token in while loops

Tags: java, while-loop, syntax, compiler-errors

For some reason the program claims that `while(n == true)`  is an unexpected token

```
boolean n = true;
while(n == true){
    if(autopark.searchItems(searchInput) == 1){
        System.out.println("There is a matching item available in our inventory\n" + "Enter a string to search: ");
    }
    if(autopark.searchItems(searchInput) == 2){
        System.out.println("No such item is available in our inventory.\n" + "Enter a string to search: ");
    }
    if(autopark.searchItems(searchInput) == 0){
        n = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the exact error? this code for `while` is 100% valid

Comment: try `while(true)` instead

Comment: @dmpokuaev please share the exact error

Comment: When i hover over the red squiggly line it states "unexpected token"

Comment: Is this code contained in a main method? Seems to be at class level where it is not allowed to be.

Comment: @k-wasilewski it is still giving me the same error

Comment: Could you please share the full code ? What is autopark ? What does searchItems do ?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put your code directly into a class. That's not where code goes.

At the 'top level' (at the start of your source file, for example), the only thing that you can write (other than comments, which are always okay) are `import` statements, `package` statements, and **type declarations**. Such as `class X {}` or `@interface Y{}` or even `enum Foo{}`.

Within a type declaration, various things are legal and it depends on the type declaration we're in to know. For basic classes, the only legal constructs within a class are **type declarations** (you can put types in types), **methods**, **constructors**, **initializers** and **field declarations**.

You cannot put code directly inside your class.

`boolean n = true;` is valid, in that it is a field declaration. But `while` is none of those things.

Try this:

```
public class MyFirstJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new MyFirstJava().go();
    }

    public void go() throws Exception {
        // start writing code here.
    }
}
```